# How to add Product in Cart in Prestashop 1.6.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add product in Cart in Prestashop 1.6.7.

But it doesn't working.

Below is my code:

```
$context=Context::getContext();//new Cart();

$id_cart=$context->cookie->__get('id_cart');
$lan_id = $this->context->language->id;
$cur_id = $this->context->currency->id;     

$products_ids=16571;
$cart=new Cart($id_cart);
$cart->id_currency=$cur_id;
$cart->id_lang=$lan_id;
$cart->updateQty(1,$products_ids, null, false);
```

But above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i manage my code as per below:

```
global $context;

$context=Context::getContext();//new Cart();

$id_cart=$context->cookie->__get('id_cart');
$lan_id = $context->cookie->__get('id_lang');
$cur_id = $context->cookie->__get('id_currency');   


$products_ids=16571;
$cart=new Cart($id_cart);
$cart->id_currency=$cur_id;
$cart->id_lang=$lan_id;
$this->context->cart->update();
$cart->updateQty(1,16571);
```

But there is one error for *carrier*

**There are no carriers available that deliver to this address.**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code at the end of your code.

```
        $this->context->cart->save();
        $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$this->context->cart->id;
        $this->context->cookie->write();
        $this->context->cart->autosetProductAddress();
        Hook::exec('actionAuthentication');
        CartRule::autoRemoveFromCart($this->context);
        CartRule::autoAddToCart($this->context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I add some static Carrier ID in

```
classes/Cart.php
```

in *getPackageList* function at line no. approx. 1892

```
if (empty($product['carrier_list'])) {
    $product['carrier_list'] = array(
                                '0' => 10,
                                '1' => 11
                               );
}
```